# How to get as many new unique IPs as possible?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, windows, ip-address

I am currently using one TOR browser and get on average 722 unique different IPs per day.

I use `MaxCircuitDirtiness` 10 which gives me a new circuit/IP every 10 seconds.

Next I set up a second tor browser where I set "`excludenodes`" and excluded the most common countries to also get the "slower" exit nodes as well, most used/fastest countries are for me:

```
ExcludeExitNodes {de},{us},{nl},{se},{ch},{pl},{fi},{ro},{fr},{at},{dk},{ca},{gb},{uk},{no},{hu},{??}
```

What else can I do to get the full range of exit nodes? I read there are between 1000-6000 exit nodes?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

well, you *should* consider using a paid GeoIP database to be more effective in your project, but - after all - it will not improve you significantly. Keep in mind that lame services will/are *filter you out*